# Ruby On Rails, gem mail, pass variables to html_part

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using gem mail for sending emails from my ruby application.

```
def send_results(user_id,filenames)


    @user=User.find(user_id)    

    mail=Mail.new do
        from "lalal.de"
        html_part do
        body File.read("/home/kik/Desktop/lal/app/views/user_mailer/analysis_process_email.html.erb") 
       body 
        end
    end
```

"/home/kik/Desktop/lal/app/views/user_mailer/analysis_process_email.html.erb" is a a html template, where I need to pass the variable filenames.

It looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper_mail">
            <div id="wrapper_mail_top">
                <h4>Welcome </h4>
                <br />
                <p>

                <br />

                <br />
                Your files are: <%= filenames %><br />
                <br />
                    m
                </p>
            </div><!-- end wrapper_top -->
lalala
```

So, I want to display the content of the the variable filenames in the email but it does not work and I do not know how to make it works.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? What should happen that isn't? What's `filenames`?

Comment: filenames is a variable that is passed to the method send_results. The content of the variable can be "group1" or "cat". It doesnt matter. Example: filenames="cat", so the user will get an email "Your files are: cat"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some similar issues. Here's my setup that solved it:

```
def feedback_notice(message)
  @sender = message.sender_id
  @message = message.content
  template = ERB.new(File.read('app/views/user_mailer/feedback_notice.text.erb')).result(binding)

  mail = Mail.new do 
    from    'from@email.com'
    to      'to@email.com'
    subject 'My Subject Line'
    body     template
  end
  mail.deliver!
end
```

Seems like the `.result(binding)` fixed it for me.

In the file `app/views/user_mailer/feedback_notice.text.erb` I was able to access the variables `@sender` and `@message`

Comment: where does `binding` come from?

Comment: @kittyminky `binding` is part of the kernel and gives the context in which the template is to be evaluated, so we can replace the correct variables with its values. Take a look at the [Binding docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Binding.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you:

File.read("/home/kik/Desktop/lal/app/views/user_mailer/analysis_process_email.html.erb").gsub("<%= filenames %>", "cat").

Thanks.